# Problem sending mail in php with http_response_code other than 200

Tags: php, email, http-response-codes

I have a problem with sending mail in PHP when I add the line "**http_response_code (503)**". The email is sent in 3 copies while if I remove the line, I have no problem, the email is sent only once. I have the same problem with PHPMailer.
Here is my code:

```
$message = 'test fg';
$to      = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = ' TEST - ' .md5(rand());            
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'test1@gmail.com',
    'Reply-to' => 'test1@gmail.com',
    'Content-type' => 'text; charset=UTF-8'
);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

http_response_code(503);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you setting response code to 503? 503 is [Service Unavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503)

Comment: It is a code for an API REST, when an error occurs I send an email and then I return an error code depending on the case (503, 400, 405, ...) with a message encoded in JSON

Comment: [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) states that `http_response_code(503);` will set the HTTP Response to `503`, and also return the old one, but you are ignoring the return value of `http_response_code()` so you only set the response code, to `503` no less.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I only had the problem with the response 503. So I replaced it with the response 500.

Comment: I am glad it works, but  500 is not a good response code either. Basically you are getting [Internal server error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). If you are setting response manually why not [Ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) or [Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) or any of the good response codes? Still can't get that.